# Github, keeping track of main WordPress theme and variations

Tags: wordpress, git, github, themes

I'm new to Git / Git hub, but want to make sure that I'm doing it right from the start.

What I'd like to do, is develop a bare framework theme, then develop separate themes based on this (styled differently).

I'd like to be able to continue working on the bare framework, and push the changes to the styled themes as needed.

I'm assuming I set up my bare framework, then clone it to make a new one?  Will further changes I then make be accessible from the new themes?  Or should I be doing it some other way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like what you want is a master branch with the bare framework and separate branches for each styled theme.

Start by creating the bare framework on master, then branch from master when you create a theme branch.

When you update the bare framework on master you can easily merge these changes to each of your theme branches.

Comment: Great, thanks - I thought that branches worked the other way round, so when a branch was done it gets merged back into the main one.  It makes sense that I can just leave them there and push back down to them!

Comment: Git supports many styles of development. Having permanent branches is a common one. In a software development project you often have one branch for continuous development and a different branch for solid releases, to which you merge the development branch at release time.